# Can Apache POI apply "color scale" conditional formatting to a range?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I can create the effect of having color scale conditional formatting (wherein the foreground color of cells vary based on how the current cell value compares to the values of all cells in the range) however I cannot seem to find an implementation of Excel's conditional formatting.  Does Apache POI have the ability to create such a formatting rule?

Comment: Are you looking at doing this for `.xls` (HSSF) or `.xlsx` (XSSF)?

Comment: Ideally XSSF, but a solution in either would be helpful.

Comment: Did you try looking at the [Apache POI Conditional Formatting example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/ConditionalFormats.java)? How close does that get you?

Comment: I did read through that, unfortunately it seems to cover everything except color scale formatting.  All of the comparison functions are formula based, so perhaps there is a formula that will work for this, but that seems like a more complicated solution than the static coloring I have already done.

Comment: What happens if you define a colour scale formatting rule in Excel (.xlsx) and read it back with Apache POI, what does that get saved as?

Comment: The getComparisonOperator returns NO_COMPARISON, and confusingly getConditionType returns 0, which is not one of the valid values.  Both formulas are null.  There is only one ConditionalFormattingRule in the Sheet.  Perhaps this style of conditional formatting doesn't use the same model as others?

Comment: Looks that way. Your best bet then is to create a bug in the [POI bugzilla instance](http://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?product=POI) for an enhancement, and upload your small sample file + the details of what you've set. I can probably help you with the next steps, but it'll be best done there not in comments here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes, in version Apache POI 3.16.

```
sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting().createConditionalFormattingColorScaleRule()
```

Read this post for details of when it was added (3.13 beta 2):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32164925/231860

Here is the unit test that shows the usage: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/testcases/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BaseTestConditionalFormatting.java

```
@Test
public void testCreateColorScaleFormatting() throws IOException {
    Workbook wb1 = _testDataProvider.createWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = wb1.createSheet();

    SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
    ConditionalFormattingRule rule1 = 
            sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingColorScaleRule();
    ColorScaleFormatting clrFmt = rule1.getColorScaleFormatting();

    assertEquals(3, clrFmt.getNumControlPoints());
    assertEquals(3, clrFmt.getColors().length);
    assertEquals(3, clrFmt.getThresholds().length);

    clrFmt.getThresholds()[0].setRangeType(RangeType.MIN);
    clrFmt.getThresholds()[1].setRangeType(RangeType.NUMBER);
    clrFmt.getThresholds()[1].setValue(10d);
    clrFmt.getThresholds()[2].setRangeType(RangeType.MAX);

    CellRangeAddress [] regions = { CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:A5") };
    sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, rule1);
```

Comment: Glad to hear it was added, I haven't migrated to the new version yet.  Thanks for updating.