# Apache POI for XSLX 3-color scale rule, How to define these method createConditionalFormattingRule() & class ConditionalFormattingThreshold.RangeType?

Tags: java, apache-poi

This method `createConditionalFormattingColorScaleRule()` is not available in any of POI releases but explained in this link [Conditional Formatting Color Scale Rule](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheetConditionalFormatting.html#createConditionalFormattingRule(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ExtendedColor))
this interface `ConditionalFormattingThreshold.RangeType` is too unavailable in all POI releases but explained in this link [Conditional Formatting Threshold Range Type](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/ConditionalFormattingThreshold.RangeType.html)

Kindly suggest whether these method/interface need to be defined by developers themselves or they are still under apache POI development for future releases?

Any help/suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As detailed in the [Apache POI Changelog](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html), the support for Conditional Formatting Colour Scale Rules was added after POI 3.13 beta 1. The first release that will contain it is 3.13 beta 2. (That should be out in a few days, until then you'd need to use a nightly build)

You can find a number of examples of setting up new Color Scale CF rules in the [Conditional Formatting unit tests](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/testcases/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BaseTestConditionalFormatting.java). Taken from there, you'll want something like

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
ConditionalFormattingRule rule1 =
            sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingColorScaleRule();
ColorScaleFormatting clrFmt = rule1.getColorScaleFormatting();

clrFmt.getThresholds()[0].setRangeType(RangeType.MIN);
clrFmt.getThresholds()[1].setRangeType(RangeType.NUMBER);
clrFmt.getThresholds()[1].setValue(10d);
clrFmt.getThresholds()[2].setRangeType(RangeType.MAX);

CellRangeAddress [] regions = { CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:A5") };
sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, rule1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Gagravarr! I couldn't get that info from SVN apache. now i understood. I was wasting my time in searching all the old POI jars.. All i need to wait for the release..Thanks.